# Why is the tangent to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ given by $y = mx + \sqrt{a^2m^2 + b^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to solve the problem of finding the minimum area made by the tangent of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ and the coordinate axes.

However, the answer book says that a tangent of said ellipse is given by $y = mx + \sqrt{a^2m^2 + b^2}$, how is that derived?

Comment: What's that $m$ means ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis The slope

Comment: This is not quite right. But it is right if for example we assume that the point of tangency is in the first quadrant, which is a perfectly fine assumption if we are trying to solve the minimal area problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is through the geometric interpretation. The ellipse and a general straight line $y = mx + n$ are tangent if and only if the system $\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1, y = mx+n$ has exactly ONE solution (as opposed to two or zero). Substitute $y$ from the second equation into the first and then set the discriminant of the resulting quadratic equation to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the ellipse

$$\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

and cut it with any line

$$  y= mx +c $$

meaning solve it for either $x$ or $y$, then what you get are two roots, one each for the two intersection points. For tangentcy situation you need a double root or repeated root or coincident point which occurs only when its discriminant

$$\Delta = 0$$

I leave this calculation to you. That's how $c$ gets modified to $\sqrt{a^2m^2 + b^2}$ and ellipse tangent to

$y = mx + \sqrt{a^2m^2 + b^2}$.